# UILabel with background view + padding that follows text layout

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to achieve a pretty complicated layout in my UICollectionViewCells where I have a UILabel that should have a white background with padding + 2px corner radius, that should follow the text.

If the text is too long it should be two lines, and the background should contain its padding. It's pretty hard to explain, but I think the picture will tell more.

Let me know if you have any solutions or suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the label inside uiview and give it a white background and play with its constraints and background colour.

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed as follow :

- Check the size of your string
- Compare it with the size of your box
- If the text size is bigger than the size of the box, you increase its size

  ```
  //Get your textfield size
  var frameRect = textField.frame;
  let myString: NSString = textField.text! as NSString

  //Get the size of your string
  let size: CGSize = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])

  //If your text doesn't fit, increase the size of your box
  if size.width > frameRect.width {
      frameRect.size.height = 50; // <-- Specify the height you want here.
      textField.frame = frameRect;
  }
  ```

Tell me if this works